# How do we paste graphics into Php Text area using CK.editor?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, textarea

Just to check how can I paste image to a text area using ck editor as my plugin in PHP?

As I have create a form for user to input and paste any image. But not sure why can't and can only key text. I try using CK editor but still can't. Here is my code.
Any advise will be great.

Please help or any good code that I can use by make use of ck editor will be great.

Thank you so much.

Thank you so much.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Styles.css">
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>


 <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="CommenterThoughts" class="form-control" rows="8" 
  cols="70"> </textarea>
                        </div>
```

Comment: _"how can I paste image to a text area "_...just read that sentence again to yourself. You want to paste **graphics** into a **text** area. How likely do you think it is that this is possible?

Comment: But it's not an issue. CKEditor allows you to generate HTML. You cannot embed images directly in HTML anyway, so the fact that CKEditor uses a text area doesn't matter. The way images are displayed in a HTML document is via an `<img>` tag, whose "src" attribute usually points to the URL of where the image file is stored on a server. CKEditor lets you upload image files to the server (there's a button on the toolbar) and then you can insert an image into your HTML (there's also a button for it) which generates an img tag pointing to where you uploaded your file.

Comment: (you can also have the "src" point to a base64-encoded version of the image data, but I get the impression that's not what you're asking about here.)

Comment: P.S. did you type "ckeditor add image" into google at all? You can find plenty of help pages telling you what to do. There is, it would appear, even a plugin which does allow you to paste images into the editor, and the plugin then automatically uploads them and generates a suitable img tag to go into the HTML. So to the user it is nice and easy, but it fulfils all the technical requirements I described above. I suggest you do a little more research of your own perhaps, in future!

Comment: Yes I type but mainly is teach us create the Upload button and not copy and paste. Do you have any idea on where to find the source code for copy and paste? Thank you.

Comment: Any help please......

Comment: I don't understand, why do you think you need the source code for copy and paste? How would that help you? I have already told you the possible solutions to your problem. You either upload the images and create image tags which point to them, or you find the plugin I mentioned which lets you copy and paste, and then handles the upload automatically.